# ListView Check if an item is selectet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

How can i check, if a item ist selectet in an ListView?

```
if(any item selectet)
{
    //do not refresh
}
else
{
   //refresh database
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ListView.SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if(ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    //do not refresh
}
else
{
   //refresh database
}
```

If this is not a winforms but ASP.NET question you can use [`ListView.SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
if(ListView1.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    //do not refresh
}
else
{
   //refresh database
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
if (ListView1.SelectedIndex !=-1 ) //-1 means no item selected
```

Comment: This works only in asp.net. OP wasn't clear about it.